# html5 to javascript use in put value of html in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This is the javascript code forming a chart

```
 series: [{

            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [ 22 , 23, 635, 203, 2]
        },
```

and this is HTML5 code

```
   <input type="number" id="num1" value="222" min="1" max="20" />
```

I want to use this input value in the data section of javascript replacing the 22 value in the chart.

Comment: It also looks like some of your question text is missing, you will need to provide more info / fill in the missing parts

Answer (score 2):

Probably you will want to get the value from the input first:

```
document.getElementById('num1').value
```

and then use it in your chart, for more details you should supply more information.

Comment: thanks buddy u r genious i add  this to convert the value into int   series: [{

                name: 'Year 1800',
                data: [ (parseInt(document.getElementById('num1').value)) , 22, 635, 203, 2]
            },